# 存在しないユーザーIDがパラメータとして送られてきた時に、HTTP エラーコードを返したい

Tags: http, rest

REST API を開発していたとします。URIパラメータとしてユーザー ID を受け取る場面で、存在しないID がパラメータに渡されたとします。

> 例: http://localhost:8080/get_public_user_info?user_id=hoge

この場合、エラーで終了するのが正しい処理なのですが、この時利用するのに適切な HTTP のリスポンスコードは何になりますでしょうか。

4xx 系だとは思うのですが、いまいちどれを選ぶべきかが明確ではないと思っているので質問しています。

Comment: 404 派です。クエリー・パラメーターも含めて URI で、それに対するリソースがない状態、という考えに基づきます。一方で知人には 400 派もいます。強く支持されている明確な指針がどこかにあれば良いのですが。

Comment: 403 Forbidden。 「APIを利用するのに必要となる適切なIDが与えられなかったため、アクセスを拒否した」という意図に、一番近いと思うから（私見）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

英語版のStackOverflowでも同じ質問がありました。参考になるかと思います。

[REST standard for GET on a resource that doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533510/rest-standard-for-get-on-a-resource-that-doesnt-exist)

私の考えでは、ユーザーが存在するかどうかを特定できるとセキュリティ上の問題になる場合は400で、そうでなければ404(ユーザーが存在しないことを区別できるようにエラーコードを分ける)が適当かなぁと思います。

Comment: FWIW: リンク先でも、そのような回答が accept されている様子ですね。